# How to prevent endless build errors in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

We are building our first big Net project: we have now 60 projects and 6 solutions. The problem is that many solutions use the same projects and it continually happens that changes to a project that is used by many solutions are not picked up, even after cleaning and rebuilding. By deleting and re-adding references, trying to build all solutions one after an other and than starting over, finally we get the code to compile again, but the situation has deteriotated to a point that each of the three developpers loses at least 45 minutes a day to get the solutions to build.
I am clutching at straws here, but below some points that may be related to the problem. Any insights are very welcome!

- We do not routinely apply new versions to a project if we make minor changes to the code.
- Some projects are maintained in Visual Studio 2012, others in Visual Studio 2013, due to lack of support for VS 2013 of the Crystal Reports engine.
- The assemblies are postprocessed by CodeContracts and PostSharp.
- We use Tortoise HG as source control. We use a hg.ignore file copied from SO. The full ignore list is:

syntax: glob

*.obj
*.exe
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.scc
*.mdf
*.ldf
*.sdf

[Bb]in

[Dd]ebug*/
obj/
[Rr]elease*/
_ReSharper*/
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.ldb
*.orig

Comment: No obvious reason for a build error, we can't see it either so nothing good to guess at.  By spreading projects across multiple solutions, you only expose yourself to the risk of using a stale reference assembly.  One that isn't getting rebuilt because it is created by another solution.  That however should never cause a build error.  It only will when you commit the crime of including a source code file in more than one project.  That's always wrong.  But very fixable.

Comment: @HansPassant We committed just that crime: meticulously including all source code of all dependent projects in the solution. That should *prevent* the use of stale dll's, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well, score one for psychic debugging.  I called it a "crime" for a reason, you already know what the jail looks like.  You shouldn't just have a problem with recompiled source no longer matching a stale assembly reference, you ought to have been battling severe type identity problems as well.  Does InvalidCastException sound familiar?  There's just no point in trying to do it this way, might as well use *one* solution that has all 60 projects.

Comment: @HansPassant I will try creating one monster solution and bear the build time it will entail :-) The largest problem is not the InvalidCastException, but the fact that VS insists on some referenced dll's and references thereto being absent, while they demonstrably are present.

Comment: Have you tried to create separate build script (using msbuild) instead of building solutions one by one ? You can start with simple <MSBuild tasks list which will build your solutions in particular order. Once you've done it - then building everything with /ds and /verbosity:diag will generate very detailed output you can walk through or post it here and we can try to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

We did go for the solution to create one "monster" solution, it took us a week to get it all sorted out. The problem has al but disappeared after that. Sometimes when changing dependencies on the lowest level of the chain of dependencies, a clean, an attempted rebuild and a restart of Visual Studio are necessary to get everything to build again.