# "Dead" namespace import stays around in Application.g.vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

After a major overhaul of our solution many namespaces were changed. However, in the Application.g.vb file of one of our WPF applications an `Imports` to a namespace that no longer exists keeps showing up and generates a warning. If I delete it, it returns, so there must be somewhere a piece of hidden code that still knows about this namespace.

The application does not hold a reference anymore to the dll that once contained this namespace and I cannot find the reference to it in the Project's xml file.

Where can this  `Imports` statement come from? Visula Studio 2013.

Comment: It is an auto-generated file, editing makes no sense.  Look through your XAML files for the identifier.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, you were right once more. Incidentallym the major overhaul was triggered by your comments to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311315/how-to-prevent-endless-build-errors-in-visual-studio .

Answer (score 0):

There turned out to be a xmlns: reference to the namespace in the Application.xaml file. Curiously a previous solution wide scan for it failed to find it.